# Primeng <p-checkbox> default state and non-editable

Tags: angular, primeng

I am new to primeng. My requirement is on page load, i have 3 rows (named A, B, C) and all 3 have a checkbox beside its name.

Now as soon as the page loads, I will get a boolean value for the checkboxes. If the flag for that field is `true` the check box should be checked and if the flag is `false` it should be unchecked. Also the check box should be non-editable. How can I achieve this (checked box and non-editable)? I tried below code but not working.

```
<p-checkbox binary="true" [value]="A.flag"><p-checkbox>
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve the issue.

```
<p-checkbox [(ngModel)]="checked" [disabled]="true"></p-checkbox>
```

In ts

```
checked: boolean = true
```